# Magento 1 create configurable / bundle product using SOAP v2

Tags: xml, magento, soap, magento-1.9

Is there a way to create configurable / bundle product using SOAP? I succeeded creating a simple product, but I cannot find a way to do so for config/bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I found an article that explains you how to do it. [check it out](http://netzkollektiv.com/blog/add-configurable-products-via-soapxml-rpc/)

Basically you have first to create the simple products, the attribute options, the configurable product and then to link children to the configurable, calling `catalogProductTypeConfigurableAssign` passing children ids and options ids in the call.

```
$client->catalogProductTypeConfigurableAssign($session, $configurableProductIdOrSku, $simpleProductIdsOrSkus,
    array('color','size'),
    array(array(
        'key'=>'color',
        'value'=>'Color'
    ),array(
        'key'=>'size',
        'value'=>'Size'
    )),
    array(
        array(
            'key' => 'yellow',
            'value' => array(
                'pricing_value' => 35,
                'is_percent' =>0
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'XL',
            'value' => array(
                'pricing_value' => 20,
                'is_percent' => 1
            )
        )
    )
);
```